# Why doesn't accepts_nested_attributes_for allow_destroy not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a nested attribute/resource, that I'm trying to destroy. What I want to do is to destroy a review object, when an associated life_hack article object is destroyed. Now I'm not too sure how the accepted_as_nested_attributes work but I'm pretty sure this is the way that I need to do it. Below i have some routes defined as so:

```
Hacklife::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'life_hacks#index'

  resources :life_hacks, only: [:new, :index, :create, :show, :destroy] do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :reviews, only: [:show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
  end
```

Below is my LifeHack article model:

```
class LifeHack < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :title, presence: true
 validates :content, presence: true

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews, allow_destroy: true
end
```

My Review Model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence: true
validates :body, presence: true
validates :rating, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0,     
less_than_or_equal_to: 6 }

has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :life_hack
end
```

Now I'm not quite sure how to fix this. Through trial by error I've used both the accepted_as_attribute_for allow destroy and the regular has_many destory methods but to no use. Could there be somthing wrong perhaps in a controller file, or maybe there is something that is not being specified in the review model? From what I understand, if you have a nested resource, you need to use an accepts_nested_attributes_for :something allow_destroy: true in order for it to work. At least that's what the activerecord rails guide made it sound. Any thoughts? Thx.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? And can you attach your lifehack controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `_destroy` key to destroy existing records.

As per this [reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) guide:

> :allow_destroy
>
> If true, destroys any members from the attributes hash with a _destroy
>   key and a value that evaluates to true (eg. 1, '1', true, or 'true').
>   This option is off by default.

If you could just show the controller details, we could better assist you. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey thanks Rajesh, sorry for the late reply. I went back to my problem and it turns out that something was wrong with my testing spec. But thanks for your reply, I appreciate it.