# accept_nested_attributes_for not working allow_destroy flag in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations, nested-form-for

allow_destroy => true does not work 
in the view:

```
% fieldset.fieldset-border 
   % br 
   . form-group 
     . col-sm-offset-1.col-sm-10 
       = P.input: first_name, label: 'Name', class: 'form-control' 
       = P.input: surname, label: 'Name', class: 'form-control' 
       = P.input: patronymic, label: 'First Name', class: 'form-control' 
       = P.input: job_position, label: 'Title', class: 'form-control' 
       = P.hidden_field: _destroy 
       = Link_to "Delete", '#', class: "remove_fields" 
   % br 
   % br
```

scripts

```
jQuery -> 
   $ ('form'). on 'click', '. remove_fields', (event) -> 
     $ (this). prev ('input [type = hidden]'). val ('1 ') 
     $ (this). closest ('fieldset'). hide () 
     event.preventDefault () 

   $ ('form'). on 'click', '. add_fields', (event) -> 
     time = new Date (). getTime () 
     regexp = new RegExp ($ (this). data ('id'), 'g') 
     $ (this). before ($ (this). data ('fields'). replace (regexp, time)) 
     event.preventDefault ()
```

model

```
class 
    ... 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for: people,: allow_destroy => true 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for: legal_entities,: allow_destroy => true 
end
```

when trying otredktirovat browser side yavaskrita hides how to 
but does not remove, and duplicate records.

[Why doesn't accepts_nested_attributes_for allow_destroy not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145254/why-doesnt-accepts-nested-attributes-for-allow-destroy-not-work)

Made from screencast 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Please show me how to fight this.

Comment: I guess you should wrap it up with the form.Try this `= p.link_to "Delete", '#', class: "remove_fields"`

Comment: I followed the way and changed link_to to p.button :submit, 'Delete', class: "remove_fields" - it didn't help - everything is the same - not behavin'

Comment: Why is your `link_to` written with a capital? That would make Ruby look for a class I think

Comment: @IliyaStepanov what are you trying to do? You have a form which doesn't have a submit button and this form is for creating an object or deleting an object?